# Android: Camera stops onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am trying to build a Camera app.

This is the code of MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static int CAMERA_REQUEST_KEY = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_KEY) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_frame);
                iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operation Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I Capture an image I get this message:
**"Unfortunately,Camera tutorial has stopped";**
Log cat says

```
11-13 21:23:00.107: E/AndroidRuntime(17967): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.cameratutorial/com.example.cameratutorial.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/20787 typ=image/jpeg (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.cameratutorial/com.example.cameratutorial.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have the camera permissions set in your manifest?

Comment: Try adding a `breakPoint` at the starting of the `onActivityResult()` and `debug` to find out exactly on which line it is crashing.

Comment: Please post the logcat

Comment: check my post and see if it works. if it still crashes post your logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have

```
  setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
```

So

```
  ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_frame);// fails
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current inflateed layout. So you need to set the content of the layout to the activity first and then initialize views.

```
ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_frame);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_KEY);
}
```

Make sure you have the required permission in manifest file

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html